# How to select row on cursor move?

Tags: python-3.x, qtablewidget, pyside6

I want to imitate list walking with arrow keys, I mean to select row when cursor goes up or down with arrow keys, like it happens when I click right-mouse-button on cell in this code, but `keyPressEvent` does not fires when I use arrows keys.

```
import sys

from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtGui import QKeyEvent
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem, QTableWidget, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from loguru import logger


class TableWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(TableWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.table_widget = QTableWidget()
        self.table_widget.cellClicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.populate_cells(data)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event) -> None:
        logger.info(f"{event.key()=}")

    def clicked(self, row, col):
        logger.info(f"{row}, {col}")
        self.table_widget.selectRow(row)

    def populate_cells(self, data):
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(len(data))
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(len(data[0]))
        for row in range(len(data)):
            for col in range(len(data[0])):
                value = data[row][col]
                self.table_widget.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem(value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_sample = [
        ["customer1", "address1"],
        ["customer2", "address2"]
    ]
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TableWindow(data_sample)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: When should `.selectRow` happen instead?

Comment: when cursor moves  up or down inside of the table

Comment: @Ronin What do you mean by ".selectRow happens when cursor trying to leave table."?

Comment: Here is the code with problem, but ok ... nothing happens when you moving cursor with cursor keys up/down/left/right inside of the table, but when you try to move cursor outside of the table `selectRow()` worked out.

Comment: `keyPressEvent` fires only when I moving cursor out of the table with cursor keys

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are listening for `keyPressEvents` on the main window when you want to be listening for them on the `QTableWidget`.

What you can do is subclass QTableWidget and reimplement the `keyPressEvent` method.

For Example:

```
class TableWidget(QTableWidget):

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        logger.info(f"{event.key()=}")
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

class TableWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(TableWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.table_widget = TableWidget()
        self.table_widget.cellClicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.populate_cells(data)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def clicked(self, row, col):
        logger.info(f"{row}, {col}")
        self.table_widget.selectRow(row)

    def populate_cells(self, data):
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(len(data))
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(len(data[0]))
        for row in range(len(data)):
            for col in range(len(data[0])):
                value = data[row][col]
                self.table_widget.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem(value))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_sample = [
        ["customer1", "address1"],
        ["customer2", "address2"]
    ]
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TableWindow(data_sample)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```